# Is there a way to configure Elasticsearch so that it will prevent creating new type in specific index?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, mapping

For example:
I have index **people** and document type **person-info**. I explicitly defined its mapping by:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/people/_mapping/person-info' -d '
{
    "person-info" : {
        "properties" : {
            // some mapping
        }
    }
}
```

Once I inserted some documents to **person_info** instead of **person-info** by mistake. So Elasticsearch automatically created new document type **person_info** with standart mapping which isn't appropriate for us. There was no warnings about this, so I didn't notice that mistake in my code. So now I have a lot of documents with different mapping.

Is there a way to configure Elasticsearch so that it will prevent creating new type in specific index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. You can disable dynamic mapping by adding the following line in your elasticsearch.yml file.

```
index.mapper.dynamic: false
```

Now if you try to index documents with type `person_info`, it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot change this behaviour: this field is mandatory and when adding a new document it is used to index it. If the field were absent Elasticsearch would not know how to index the document. If a mapping for that type is missing a default one is created.

The only thing you can do is disabling the dynamic mapping creation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html

Comment: I think the point of such a setting, should it exist, would be that the index operation fails entirely if the mapping for that type does not exist.